# Matrix representation of linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T$ is defined by $T(p(x))=p'(x)$

$B$ is the basis $\{1,x \}$

Now the book is telling me that $[T]_B$ is the matrix 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
why isn't it
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Is this a mistake or am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Certainly $T$ is nilpotent of order $2$. Your matrix is, whereas the proposed one isn't. You've got it right

Answer (score 0):

$T(1)=0=0+0x$

$T(x)=1=1+0x$

So \begin{equation}[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix}T(1),T(x) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\end{equation}
and it seems as if the book is indeed incorrect.